# ByteArray To XML file in Android

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-xml

I am sending a file in byte[] format from web service to android device.

1. If that file is an XML file i.e. byte[] array then how could i convert it to original XML file.
2. If that file is an image i.e. byte[] array then how could i convert it to original Image.

I am using android sdk 2.2 on samsung galaxy tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Webservice should send you some identifier about the file type. whether the byte array is for image or is for general file. then only you can know about which type of file it is. after knowing file type you can convert the byte array into your desired file type. Also you can write to file. If you want to print that xml in logcat you can use

```
String xmlData = new String(byte[] data); System.out.println(xmlData)
```

**create a file (whether xml or image or anything) if you know the file format**

```
String extension = ".xml"//or ".jpg" or anything
String filename = myfile+extension;
byte[] data = //the byte array which i got from server
File f = new File(givepathOfFile+filename );

        try {
            f.createNewFile();

            // write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(data );
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: ok but what i want to ask is that how could 1)i convert an byte[] array to an xml file.

Comment: ok i got it thanks for ur help, can you help again on how could i get the byte[] array from web service in android i.e.  SoapPrimitive result=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); is it right that i would get byte[] array in result?

Answer (score 0):

A byte array containing XML **already is** an XML document.  If you want to make it an XML file, then just write the bytes to a file.

The same applies for an image file.

Are you really just asking how to write a byte array as a file?

---

Here's how to write bytes to a file in Java.

```
byte[] bytes = ...
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("someFile.xml");
try {
    fos.write(bytes);
} finally {
    fos.close();
}
```

Note that you need to close an opened stream in a `finally` block or else you risk leaking a file descriptors.  If you leak too many file descriptors, later attempts to open files or sockets could start failing.

Comment: Yes that is what i want to know means how can i receive an byte[] in android from soap web service and how to convert that byte[] to XML document so that i can save it to device.

Comment: ok i got it thanks for ur help, can you help again on how could i get the byte[] array from web service in android i.e. SoapPrimitive result=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); is it right that i would get byte[] array in result?

Comment: That's a different question.  Ask a new Question.  (FWIW, I've no idea ... I don't use SOAP.)